# MarkLogic Windows installation "Server Install" page hangs

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

After a fresh install of MarkLogic 8 on a Windows 7 machine (for development purposes), I start the server using "run as administrator" and then launch the admin web console which takes me to the "Server Install" page.  I get this message "This server must now self-install the initial databases and application servers. Click OK to continue." and I click the OK button and the browser just hangs.  I left it on overnight and it was still hung the next morning and I've rebooted/refreshed/cleared cache and tried it and it still just hangs.

I didn't see any mention of this in the MarkLogic docs, nor here or any other location via Google.  Is there a log file location or something that I can look for to begin troubleshooting this?

Comment: Look at `C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Logs\ErrorLog.txt` and post anything relevant, like errors or warnings.

Comment: Can you give us the specific MarkLogic version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, running it in Chrome works fine (I was using IE before).  There were no entries in the error log for anything, so I'm wondering if the request was ever even submitted by the browser...

Comment: We have never been successful in installing via IE at our company. Using it after install -fine. Install - nope.